# Skip Spring placeholder substitution

Tags: java, spring

I'm using Spring properties placeholders in my application. One of my properties values contains something Spring interprets as a placeholder, but I don't want it:

```
@Value("${propertyName}")
private String property;
```

My property is well defined:

```
propertyName=Welcome ${name}
```

Without surprise I get an error :

> Could not resolve placeholder 'name' in value "Welcome ${name}"

propertyName  is something I want to interpret myself, so I don't want ${name} to be resolved by Spring. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape dollar (`$`) in that case. So that spring doesn't treat this as a property.

```
propertyName=Welcome #{'$'}{name}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean and set `ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders` as `true`, this should work. But keep in mind that this will affect all placeholders in that context.